# Notepad++ Regex Find line containing a word and not containing a word

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to use notepad++ and regex to find a line that contains the word `g_n` and does not contain the word `thd`.

I've been desperately trying to figure this out but with little luck. Can someone point me in the right direction? It would be greatly appreciated.

I know that I can use ^ to negate something.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would imagine that this regex would work:

```
^(?!.*thd).*g_n.*$
```

Comment: I just used this to remove from view all the comments in filebeat.yml file. GREAT WORK!!! ^(?!.*#). worked flawlessly!